# I am getting a "not a statement" error on a for each loop

Tags: java, for-loop

The problem seems to be in the increment, but I need it to decrease by 2. The "length" variable is for the length of a series of numbers

```
public int longMethodName()
{
    int length = cardNumber.length();
    longMethodName = 0
        for(int i=length-1; i<0; i-2)
        {
            int cardNumberInt = Integer.parseInt(cardNumber.charAt(i));
            int tempVar = cardNumberInt*2;
            longMethodName = longMethodName + tempVar;
        }
    return longMethodName;
}
```

Comment: Which line is the error on? What's the exact error message?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change it to `i=i-2` or `i-=2` to decrement by 2.

You might be trying to emulate the `i++`/`i--` syntax, which is simply shorthand for `i = i+1` or `i=i-1`. However, that syntax only works for change by 1 (formally speaking `++` and `--` are unary operators ), so `i-2` won't work directly.

You also need to fix the other errors, as detailed in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

1.) `longMethodName = 0` // Semicolon missing

2.) `i-2`, need to change to `i = i-2`

3.) `Integer.parseInt()`, `cardNumber.charAt(i)`returns `char` which is not allowed

Answer (score 0):

You can also use i-=2 so you don't have to write i a second time ;-)